# How do I copy multiple values from one table to another? (multiple rows)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My database is as follows :

`Table A :   id   | value1 | value2`

`Table B : value0 | value1 | value2`

What I have to do is copy all the content from the mentioned columns from all the rows in `Table A` into new rows in `Table B`. Is this possible?

- the value from id goes into `value0`;
- there are more columns in both tables, but they are not required;
- with the exception of id, the other columns have the same names;
- All columns have the same data type as their counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into b(value0, value1, value2)
    select id, value1, value2
    from a;
```

Comment: I tried that, but it gives me this error : the subquery returned more than 1 value. That is not allowed when the subquery follows a =,!=,<,<=,>,>= or when it is used as an expression.

Comment: @LuccasK . . . This answer has no subquery, so it cannot give that error.

Comment: I don't know what to say. I performed your exact answer and it gave me the error I mentioned.

Comment: @LuccasK . . . That could occur if `a` is a view or if you have a trigger on `b`.  This query cannot return that problem.

Comment: That must be it then. No idea how to check on that.

Comment: Found the problem. There is indeed a trigger on b. Thank you so much!